# Writing a text to a file including af mixture of signs

Tags: export

I'm trying to write this to a file:

j/?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

However, when using WriteString, the "-marks are not accepted. 
If I use Write, however, the "-marks are accepted, but then the /, #, < - marks are not.

Can you help?

Comment: Please, edit your question to reflect the fact that you are trayin to export a XML snippet and not just a string. Format the code properly to show its true nature.

Comment: If you don't need to stream to a file, you may find it easier to use `Export`.

Answer (score 1):

the reason it's not working it's because `"` is a special character, so you need to put `\` before it to make Mathematica recognize it as a part of a string.

```
WriteString["myFile", "j/?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"]
```

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html